# Css Image Handling without using media queries

Tags: html, css

Can anyone please let me know how to handle the images sizes(width and height) in all the ways such as potrait and landscape views for laptops, pc's, ipad and mobile screens. but without using the media queries.

One time I use to get larger images and some time I am getting smaller images, but I want to show all the images of same size using only normal css without using any media queries.

Please do the needful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually it is preferred that the image resolution should be **responsive for responsive layouts**... it means that image size should be `width:100%` and `height:auto` in css and same for html, image will arrange on any of the screens....

Remember to add this line on the head tag above on your page:-

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a max-width style property as 100%, on bigger resolutions your image will contain it's normal size and on smaller windows like on mobile phones the image will become the width of your screen (container). The image will scale proportionally.

```
<img src="sample.jpg" style="max-width:100%;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="img1.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />
<img src="img2.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />
```

...

Comment: Hi Jane, If am using this for a smaller image then its visibility is not good at all. Any other method. I used 100% width and height.

Answer (score 0):

you can set height and width in css itself

for eg if are using a div id as sample_div_img then use the following code

```
#sample_div_img img{
height:100px;
width:100px
}
```

in php / html

```
<div id='sample_div_img>
 <img src='sample.jpg'>
</div>
```

one thing if image size is different from the mentioned in css, image may be looks blurring

Let me know any issues in this